# How to render layout into var?

Tags: magento

I have controller action. It's called via ajax request. Action should return json object.
I know how to return json from action. It's no problem.

In the action I created associative-array with to keys 'cart' and 'search'. Each element should contain parsed layout for appropriate thing: cart layout and search layout.

So question is how to render/parse layout into var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found answer myself.

```
$var = $this->getLayout($action_handle)->getOutput();
```

Now $var will contain layout html.